# how can I wait for 2 promises that check status of URLs to be completed before stating a new promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch

Ho everyone

Got issue with setting promises and playing with results.

I have 2 arrays of URLs defined and objectives is to filter files (using fetch) by keeping only those that exists, then once completed trigger a function that shows the results.

I would like to use promise methodology and fetch() function.

I have create 1 promise per array that filters only existing files. I need to wait before the 2 promises are completed before triggering another function.

I looked at internet and tried multiple ways but cannot make it working as I expect. it shows the results but I cannot play with them so I may have done it wrongly.

Happy to get some helps !

See below my code :

```
const Primary = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',       //file exists
    '/data/file01',                                     //file dont exist
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',       //file exists
    '/data/file02'                                      //file dont exist
];

const Diverse = [
    '/data/file0.txt',                                  //file dont exist
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',      //file exists
    '/data/file5.txt'                                   //file dont exist
];

const P1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Primary.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        fetch( elem )
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status != 404) {
                arr1.push (response.url);
                return (response.url);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error ", error);
        });
        if (index==(Primary.length-1))
            resolve (arr1);
    });
});

const P2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Diverse.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        fetch( elem )
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status != 404) {
                arr2.push (response.url);
                return (response.url);
                }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error ", error);
        });
        if (index==(Diverse.length-1))
            resolve (arr2);
    });
});

// Promise.all waits until all jobs are resolved
Promise.all( [P1, P2] )
.then(function (responses) {
    console.log ('Responses:', responses);
    responses.forEach(function (element, index) {
        console.log (element);
        element.forEach(function (el, id) {
            console.log (el);
        });
    });

    console.log('Test sync');
});
```

Thanks again
Alex

Answer (score 1):

This does not work properly as you wrote P1, P2 functions in a wrong way.

```
Diverse.forEach(function (elem, index) {
...
  if (index==(Primary.length-1))
    resolve(arr);
}
```

^This is really bad practice as JS is synchronous and does not return result that you want.
Please rewrite functions like this -

```
const P2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fetchPromises = Diverse.map((elem, index) => fetch(elem));
    Promise.all(fetchPromises)
        then(responses => resolve(responses))
});
```

Happy coding!

Comment: @Alex great. please mark this as answer if it helps you to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback to get the result back to you, synchronous function will not return any result that you want.

```
const Primary = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',       //file exists
    '/data/file01',                                     //file dont exist
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',       //file exists
    '/data/file02'                                      //file dont exist
];

const Diverse = [
    '/data/file0.txt',                                  //file dont exist
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',      //file exists
    '/data/file5.txt'                                   //file dont exist
];

const doFetch = (url) => fetch(url).then(response=>{
    let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        if(response.status == 200){
            resolve(response.json())
        }else{
            reject(response.status)
        }
    })

    return promise
})

let callback = {
    success: (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error:(err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    }
}

Primary.map( (url) => {
    doFetch(url)
    .then(callback.success, callback.error)
})

Diverse.map( (url) => {
    doFetch(url)
    .then(callback.success, callback.error)
})
```

Comment: I have tried without sucess to use your doFetch functions within 1 promises. As I like your function, I 'd like to use it to chech the Primary array and the secondary array in parallel using promise.all. Then once both are completed and only once they are completed, I will show the results . Cannot figure out how to handle it. I always got errors.....cheers Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Something like this should work

```
Promise.add(Primary.map(fetch)).then((allResponsens) => ...);
```

Promise.all will resolve once all of the promises provided as an argument resolve.

You can also use [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) if you don't care about catching network errors